# The function client side is not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function abc()
    {
        return confirm('are U sure?');
    }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="abc()" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px" />
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above page whether you click <kbd>ok</kbd> or <kbd>cancel</kbd> for confirmation box the processing transfer for server why?

Comment: Formatted your code for you; indent code by 4 spaces rather than using [code] tags.

Comment: View the generate page source and look at your button. Looking at that is always better than staring at the serverside code for the error.

Comment: Either your ASP isn't generating the HTML and JS that you want, or the JS isn't doing what you want on the generated HTML. Try to narrow the question down to one or the other. Either ask why the ASP isn't outputting the HTML you want, or show the HTML that is sent to the browser rather then the ASP source.

Comment: how about <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return abc()">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
 OnClientClick="return abc();"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you are asking why when you click Button1 is it posting back to the server?

This is because its a **server control**.

If you want a simple client button it would look like the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Button" OnClick="abc()" style="height: 26px" />
```

This would mean no processing on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a server control, the submit even is being fired as well.

The return false (which you would get by clicking 'cancel') may stop the onclick event, however the onsubmit event is still being fired.

You could try capturing this instead of the onclick event.